# If element in array 1 is larger than element in array 2 then

Tags: if-statement, fortran

Im new to using fortran and im having some problems with an if statement. Im trying to write something along the lines of if element in array 1 is larger than element in array 2 then let h = some expression, else h = 0. I have coppied my code below

```
  DO I=1,NPOIN 

  IF ((X(I)*COS(0.0)+0.0*Y(I)*COS(0.0)+0.1)*0.15 .GT. ZF(I)) THEN  
    H%R(I) =0.15*((X(I)*COS(0.0))+(0.0*Y(I)*COS(0.0))+0.1)
  ELSE
    H%R(I) = 1 
  ENDIF

  ENDDO
```

The error im getting is:

```
 IF ((X(I)*COS(0.0)+0.0*Y(I)*COS(0.0)+0.1)*0.15 .GT. ZF(I)) THEN  

Error: Syntax error in IF-expression at (1)
```

Apologies if this is somethign really obvious but ive tried all sorts to fix it with no joy so far. Any help would be appreciated.

There may be a better way to compare the two arrays but yeah essentially im trying have ZF as my main array, but where H is larger than ZF i want the ZF value to be replaced with the H value. SO essentially i have a new array with the maximum value possible between the two arrays.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The expression compiles fine... I assumed `real :: X(NPOIN), Y(NPOIN), ZF(NPOIN), R(NPOIN)` and exchanged 'H%R' -> 'R'. Maybe there is something else going wrong. Could you post something compilable?

Comment: This expression -- `(X(I)*COS(0.0)+0.0*Y(I)*COS(0.0)+0.1)` -- occurs twice in your code and can be reduced to `X(I)+0.1`.  I can't see the extra terms as the source of the problem you report but they get in your way, and ours, in trying to understand what is going on.  Get rid of them.

Comment: if using fixed source form be sure not to go past col 72.

Comment: Read about the MERGE statement in Fortran 90 and later versions of the language.

Answer (score 2):

*There may be a better way to compare the two arrays but yeah essentially im trying have ZF as my main array, but where H is larger than ZF i want the ZF value to be replaced with the H value. SO essentially i have a new array with the maximum value possible between the two arrays.*

If `h` and `zf` have the same shape you can simply write:

```
where (h>zf) 
    zf = h
end where
```

If they don't have the same shape clarify what you are trying to do.

(Modern) Fortran is an array language (up to a first approximation) so think whole-array operations  rather than loops.  They may be faster, more likely they're not, but they're quicker to write and easier to understand.  If performance isn't good enough then think about a `do` loop replacement.

Comment: Or even `zf=MAX(zf,h)`?  Performance may well be even worse than the `where` construct but it could be clearer in intention.

Comment: @francescalus: yes, even better your way.